# Linq query that returns entire rows based on a distinct column value

Tags: linq

I need to return all columns of a record from the `Customers` that is distinct by the column `ShipTo`. I tried this query using `Distinct()`, but it returns duplicate records:

```
var query = (from o in Orders
             from c in Customers
             where (from x in CustomerOrders
                    where x.CustomerId == customerId
                    && !x.OrderType.Equals('A')
                    select x.OrderId).Contains(o.OrderId)
             && c.CustomerId == customerId
             && c.ShipTo == o.ShipTo
             && !o.OrderStatus.Equals('C')
             select c).Distinct();
```

I then tried to rewrite the query using `Group By` and `First()`. I didn't get any syntax errors, but the query throws an exception when testing with LinqPad.

```
var query = (from o in Orders
             from c in Customers
             where (from x in CustomerOrders
                    where x.CustomerId == customerId
                    && !x.OrderType.Equals('A')
                    select x.OrderId).Contains(o.OrderId)
             && c.CustomerId == customerId
             && c.ShipTo == o.ShipTo
             && !o.OrderStatus.Equals('C')
             group c by c.ShipTo into g
             select g.First());
```

Comment: "all columns of a `Customer` but distinct by `ShipTo`" sounds like a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Duh! I needed to add `orderby c.ShipTo`. It's now working for me as desired.

```
var query = (from o in Orders
             from c in Customers
             where (from x in CustomerOrders
                    where x.CustomerId == customerId
                    && !x.OrderType.Equals('A')
                    select x.OrderId).Contains(o.OrderId)
             && c.CustomerId == customerId
             && c.ShipTo == o.ShipTo
             && !o.OrderStatus.Equals('C')
             orderby c.ShipTo
             select c).Distinct();
```

Comment: That still won't do a `Distinct()` on the `ShipTo` column.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all the customers (each once) that have *any* order assigned via `CustomerOrders` where the the customer's and the order's `ShipTo` are the same plus some other constraints on `OrderType` and `OrderStatus` (plus the filter on `customerId`, which seems to limit the result set to at most one).

That would come to:

```
var qCustomer =
    from c in Customers
    where c.CustomerId == customerId && 
    (
        from co in CustomerOrders where co.CustomerId == c.CustomerId && co.OrderType != 'A'
        join o in Orders on co.OrderType equals o.OrderId where o.OrderStatus != 'C' && o.ShipTo == c.ShipTo
        select 1
    ).Any()
    select c;
```

or equivalently

```
var qCustomer =
    (
    from c in Customers
    join co in CustomerOrders on c.CustomerId equals co.CustomerId
    join o in Orders on co.OrderId equals o.OrderId
    where c.CustomerId == customerId && co.OrderType != 'A' && o.OrderStatus != 'C' && c.ShipTo == o.ShipTo
    select c
    ).Distinct();
```

Since there is at most one customer with that ID:

```
var customerOrNull = qCustomer.SingleOrDefault();
```